# How are split inteins joined?

Tags: proteins, protein-binding, ligation

Do they form a peptide bond? Or is it just some affinity/van der Waals interaction?

Is the mechanism enzyme catalized?

Are the residues/moieties at the join site known? Could they be introduced to synthesized peptide fragments to achieve something like native chemical ligation?

Comment: Exteins are joined; Inteins are removed and van der Waals interactions are non-bonding interactions and it is definitely not the case. Can you narrow down your post to a specific issue (perhaps the last one as it seems non-trivial) but you have to add more details.

Comment: I really mean the joining of the split inteins, which in my understanding must happen before the whole intein (consisting of 2 split intein parts) can be removed. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intein#Split_inteins